# Does anyone know more about the relief painting in the bedroom in "Pandora's Box" (1929)?

Tags: props, pandoras-box-1929

In *Pandora's Box* (1929) by G. W. Pabst, there is a relief image of a person in the bedroom, around 0:50; see right upper corner:

[image: the scene in the bedroom]

Another screencap of the relief image:

[image: screencap of relief painting/image]

<sup>Image source: https://scenebygreen.files.wordpress.com/2023/07/videoscreenshot-youtube-louisebrooksinpandorasbox1929hdengsubs-5929.png</sup>

Does anyone know more about this image? Similar images at this time? Any references?

And a very, very naive question: the famous Han Solo in carbonite [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Han_Solo_in_Carbonite_(31649435213).jpg)—is there any chance it has anything to do with this kind of art work?

Comment: Are you certain it is a painting and not a sculpture?

Comment: @M.A.Golding The OP correctly calls it a [relief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relief).